# Problemas con redireccionamiento luego de inicio de sesion en php

Tags: php

Tengo una pagina con un formulario de inicio de sesion. Cuando inicia sesion me aparece un aviso que inicie sesion correctamente, pero tengo un if que si esta establecida una sesion que me muestre otro formulario, sin embargo la pagina no me lo muestra.

Tambien trate que me redireccione a otra pagina y cuando pasa esto me tira un error que trate de redireccionar muchas veces y no carga nada.

El codigo es este:

"index.php":

```
<?php

session_start();
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "buffet");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form Using Ajax In PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <div id="message">
            </div>
            <form class="login-form" id="loginform" action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su email" name="email" id="email"/>
                <span id="uemail"></span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" name="password" id="password"/>
                <span id="upass" name="upass"></span>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" id="submt" value="Iniciar Sesion">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION["idUsuario"]) && !empty($_SESSION["idUsuario"])): ?>
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <div id="message">
                </div>
                <form class="changepassword-form" id="changepasswordform" action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" placeholder="" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="<?= $_SESSION["idUsuario"] ?>"/>
                    <span id="uemail"></span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su antigua contraseña" name="oldpassword" id="oldpassword"/>
                    <span id="oldpass"></span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su nueva contraseña" name="newpassword" id="newpassword"/>
                    <span id="newpass"></span>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" id="submt" value="Cambiar Contraseña">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>    
</body>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#loginform").on("submit",function(e){

        $('#uemail').html('');
        $('#upass').html('');
        $('#message').html('');

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if($("#email").val() == ""){
            $("#uemail").html("Por favor, ingrese su email");
            $("#uemail").css("color", "red");
            $("#email").css("border", "1px solid grey");
            $("#email").focus();
        }

        else if($("#password").val()==""){
            $("#upass").html("Por favor, ingrese su contraseña");
            $("#upass").css("color", "red");
            $("#password").css("border", "1px solid grey");
            $("#password").focus();
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ajaxLogin.php",
                data:{"email":email,"password":password},
                success:function(result){
                    //alert(result);
                    if(result==1){
                        //alert("invalid");
                        $("#message").html("Email o Contraseña Incorrecta");
                        $("#message").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#message").html("Se ingreso exitosamente");
                        $("#message").css("color", "green");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

"ajaxLogin.php"

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "buffet");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$userquery = $con->query("SELECT * from Usuario where Email='".$email."' and Contraseña='".$password."'");

$numrows = $userquery->num_rows;

if($numrows>0){
    $data = $userquery->fetch_array();

    $_SESSION["idUsuario"] = $data["idUsuario"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $data["Nombre"];

    echo 0;
}
else{
    echo 1;                 
}                       
?>
```

El error no se donde se encuentra exactamente. Que es mejor, que una vez que ingreso me lleve a otra pagina, o que actualice la misma mostrando otra informacion?

Comment: ¿El problema en sí cuál es, que no redirecciona? ¿Dónde ocurre el problema? Es que preguntas varias cosas cuyas respuestas estarían basadas en opiniones.

Comment: Acabo de hacer ciertas ediciones para un mejor entendimiento

Comment: Utiliza el web inspector para ver que te envia si llama correctamente, y demas, por que creas dos sesiones, espero que no se te este olvidando pasar el parametro que falta para la conexion a mysql